# Why there isn't enough attention for Network services questions?

Tags: support

This site is for Unix and Linux question and I think that Network Services configuration and management is an important part of it so why the question that related to this domain don't get enough attention

for example:
Squid (30 view, 1answer) [How can we make Squid do a reverse nslookup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134132/how-can-we-make-squid-do-a-reverse-nslookup)

DNS (35 view) [how to nsupdate remotely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131543/how-to-nsupdate-remotely/131550#131550)

Is this site for this questions or Not, so why they are left out like this, and Is there a better site than `Unix and Linux` for this services?

Answer (score 4):

2 questions is hardly a valid sample to reach any sort of conclusion. I can pick 
[any](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132837)
[number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132761)
[of](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132847)
[questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132129)
[with](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133926)
[a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133970)
[lower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133991)
[view](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133922)
[count,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133988)
[and](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133995)
[none](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133997)
[of](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134034)
[them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133932)
[are](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136278)
[network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132015)
[related.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134125)

Plus we have [your very own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132779/how-to-read-an-ip-address-backwards) which is also DNS related, and has currently received 1,891 views.

Answer (score 1):

We can surely answer those questions here but they're probably more suited to Server Fault. I along with a few others can answer them but we are only a few users on this site. The vast majority probably cannot or choose not to. IMO!